# How do you position div's in html5?

Tags: css, html

I have been for hours attempting to get several div's to display and align properly. I have looked all over the internet and I just cannot get it right.

What I want is inside a section determined by a theme of a wordpress page, is the title of the space in the top left of that section, an info box to the left of the title, and below both of those a section containing a table.

At this point, I Just need to make a typical web page where I can build the thing i am building and I can worry about adding it into wordpress later.

|-----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
|.......................Title......................|...........................Info.....................|
|-----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
|..........................................................................................................|
|.................................................Table.................................................|
|..........................................................................................................|
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

Why that is so hard is beyond me.

The other problem is that I wish for this to be browser independent. I would like to figure out a way for it to be displayed in just such a manner on a desktop computer or a tablet or phone screen. (This may not be possible without a little effort but I thought I'd throw it out there.)

The html generated by php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Knights Tour</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://bmfmain/kt/game.css">
<script src="http://bmfmain/kt/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>Knight's Tour</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="info">
        <p>adsf</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="section">

    <table id="game">
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="0"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="1"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="2"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="3"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="4"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="5"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="6"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="7"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="8"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="9"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="10"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="11"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="12"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="13"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="14"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="15"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="16"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="17"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="18"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="19"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="20"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="21"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="22"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="23"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="24"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="25"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="26"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="27"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="28"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="29"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="30"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="31"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="32"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="33"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="34"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="35"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="36"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="37"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="38"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="39"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="40"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="41"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="42"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="43"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="44"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="45"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="46"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="47"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="48"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="49"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="50"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="51"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="52"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="53"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="54"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="55"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="56"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="57"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="58"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="59"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="60"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="61"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="62"></td>  
            <td class="tdcls" name="63"></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>

</div>
<script src="http://bmfmain/kt/game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Formatting slightly off due to copy/paste.

The css that is currently being used: (Will change as I work the problem.)

```
html, body 
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#header
{
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: top;
padding: 5px;

}
#title
{
width: 400px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
position: absolute;
}
#info
{
width: 400px;
text-align: center;
float: right;
position: absolute;
}
#section
{
width: 800px;
height: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: bottom;

}
table 
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
table, th, td 
{
border: 1px solid #0000cc;
border-spacing: 0.0rem;
}
th, td 
{
width: 8%;
height: 8%;
text-align: center;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Again, formatting is off due to not being able to copy/paste code straight into stackexchange.com.

The question is:
How do I make the div's appear like the picture above?
How do I make the div's appear like the picture above on any platform, computer, tablet, or phone?

Thank you.

[Current live example:](http://freethecube.com/kt/)

Comment: For a start the question contains many questions, for one if you want to target a certain device try looking at css @media queries

Comment: and responsive design or twitter-bootstrap that has no CSS with fixed height / width size

Comment: There is only one question. How do I arrange the div's in the manner I posted above. I placed a link to a live demo so people can see what it is doing. Can you please provide an answer of some kind.

Comment: @Joel both comments have a sense with your issue. Consider learning and investigating those comments to solve your issues. Your current solution will never work as your screen resolution is different from mine and.. There fore your display will be different too.

Comment: No one is insulting you, we started trying to help you until you decided you weren't interested in our opinion

Comment: Joel, I think you need to calm down. No one is insulting you here. Kepoly merely suggested that it wasn't clear what you were asking, which is a good opportunity to focus the question to your core issue. aorfevre provided a suggestion for techniques they believed would be helpful. They're trying to help, and rather than lashing out at them I'd pay attention to their suggestions. If they don't apply, that might be a signal that you could clarify your question or take this to heart the next time you asked a question.

Comment: Please don't re-add your rant, especially when already removed by a moderator. I've locked the question to prevent further mishaps like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organizing elements of a web page into columns can actually be quite difficult. Two common solutions to the problem are using bootstrap and flexbox. 

I use Bootstrap because I am already familiar with it, its sort of the holygrail of HTML/CSS/JS frameworks. Your gonna need to learn some basic familiarity with bootstrap before understanding and working with the resource Im going to point you to. This is well worth the time though, it will make your life much easier. Heres an explanation on using the Bootstrap grid system http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/. Also check out youtube video tutorials, there are also some great tutorials on [lynda.com](http://lynda.com).

Edit: Heres how I'd go about doing it. First add Bootstrap to your website, easiest way is with a CDN so you can just add a link to the top of your page (although not necessarily the best way to do it). Many resources online on how to add bootstrap.

heres the html code to get you started (this will work when you add bootstrap):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="title">
        <h1>Knight's Tour</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6" id="info">
        <p>adssdfksdafhsadkhfkashdfksahdkfhakdshfkasdhfkhaskf</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="table">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also notice that bootstrap handles all the responsiveness for different size screens.

Comment: How about a suggestion on how to apply the suggested bootstrap to my particular situation? What specifically about my HTML is "FUBAR?"

Comment: I see you are using ul/li for the actual table. Being that I am writing a game where i need to specifically reference each cell individually, how is ul/li better? You can go to my live example and see just how I am referencing the table cells via jquery. Whats the difference?

Comment: Its not better, i just did that for the example because its easier to type out :)

Comment: http://freethecube.com/kt/ :)

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished what I was attempting to do above with the following html and bootstrap.

```
echo '
<body>
    <div class="container gamepage">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 ">
                <br><p><img style="float: left;" class"gamepics" src="' . $url . '/pics/Knight.png"' . ' alt="Knight"><h1 style="float: right;" >Knight\'s Tour</h1></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 visible-lg">
                <h3 class="infobox" name="infobox"><p>text</p><p>text</p></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                <p></p>
                <p>
                    Knight\'s Tour is a game of a traveling chess piece. The Knight moves in "L" shaped patterns across the board, and the purpose of this game is to find each and every square of the board with the Knight using each square only once.
                </p>
                <p>
                    The Knight can move one space over and two up or two spaces over and one up. The piece can move in any direction, in the one and two pattern. You can start anywhere. Just click a board square. Good Luck!
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="resetboard" type="button" value="Reset Board" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="backmove" type="button" value="Back One" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 hidden-lg">
                <h3 class="infobox" name="infobox"><p>text</p><p>text</p></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                <table id="game" class="gametable">';
```

As you can see from the various `col` class statements, bootstrap is arranging my content in a number of ways. These statements apply also to many different devices including phones.

[Excellent Bootstrap Guide](http://fearlessflyer.com/exploring-the-bootstrap-3-0-grid-system/)

[Very In-depth Guide by Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)